# Need to sum up the checked text box values in telerik grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid

i have created a telerik grid for small payment module
in this module i have selected two checkbox and enter a amount,i need the total amount to be displayed in the donation amount label

[image]

The current code is to sum up the values displayed in the second column,and saving the values in session and passsing to next page.

Gridview

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn3 column" UniqueName="TemplateColumn3">
                                        <ItemTemplate> 
                              <asp:TextBox ID="txt_amnt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> </td> 
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

c# code

```
protected void chk_box_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["dt"].ToString().Trim() != "NULL")
            {

                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];

            }

            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Id");
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
            }


            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)sender;

            if (chk.Checked == true)
            {

                dt.Rows.Add();
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1 ]["Id"] = ((Label)chk.FindControl("lb_id")).Text.Trim();
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = ((Label)chk.FindControl("lb_donation")).Text.Trim();
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Amount"] = ((Label)chk.FindControl("lb_amount")).Text.Trim();
                // dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count + 1]["chkstatus"] = ((Label)chk.FindControl("lb_amount")).ToString().Trim();

            }
            else {


                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(((Label)chk.FindControl("lb_id")).Text.Trim()==dt.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString().Trim())
                    { dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i); }

                }

            }
            ViewState["dt"] = dt;
            double tamount = 0;
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dt.Rows.Count; i2++)
            {


                tamount = tamount + Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i2]["Amount"]);


            }

            lb_tamount.Text = tamount.ToString() ;

        }
```

Comment: What is this new control `Checked textbox`?

Comment: yes when i checked the textbox the values in the text box which has been checked has to be sumed up

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code for the CheckBox will always hit error. 
How can you find a control inside a CheckBox ? Secondly your code is not complete as per the result you are showing. Anyway here is the idea how you can get checked item in your RadGrid.

First you need loop the RadGrid to get all checked CheckBox.
Then sum up the total and put it to the label.

This code just to mock up for your scenario. Please use TryParse to get the int value to ensure no converting error.

Code Behind

```
protected void chkCheck_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Variable
    int total = 0;
    int amt = 0;
    int donateAmt = 0;

    foreach (GridDataItem item in rg.Items)
    {
        // Find Control
        CheckBox chkCheck = item.FindControl("chkCheck") as CheckBox;
        Label lblAmount = item.FindControl("lblAmount") as Label;
        TextBox txtAmount = item.FindControl("txtAmount") as TextBox;

        // Reset Amount
        amt = 0;
        donateAmt = 0;

        // Check
        if (chkCheck != null && chkCheck.Checked)
        {
            // Check & Get Value
            if (lblAmount != null && txtAmount != null)
            {
                // Check & Set
                if (lblAmount.Text.Trim() != string.Empty) 
                    amt = Convert.ToInt32(lblAmount.Text.Trim());

                // Check & Set
                if (txtAmount.Text != string.Empty) 
                    donateAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text.Trim());

                // Check current Amount in stock and donate amt
                if (donateAmt > amt)
                {
                    donateAmt = amt;
                    txtAmount.Text = donateAmt + "";
                }

                // Reset to the text 

            }

            total += donateAmt;         
        }
    }

    lblTotal.Text = total + "";
}
```